# New Year's Eve in Berlin and Luggage Storage

Tags: luggage-storage, berlin, public-holidays

We, a small group of 3 people (19 years old), are looking to do new year's eve in Berlin. We will arrive at around 14.00 and we will have a flight back at 07.35 on 01/01/2018.

We are arriving from Leipzig and we are on kind of a low budget. We thought about leaving our luggage in the *SXF* airport, but the storage is under maintenance (checked with them and will still be in December). So we were thinking about leaving big luggage in the main station on 31/12, and take it back in the early morning of 01/01.

We have some questions that we hope you could answer:

1. Is the Branderburg Gate the best place, even for young people? We love techno and know that Berlin has some good places, but we think that on the 31st of December it may be not the best thing to do to go in a disco club.
2. Is the main station the best place to leave luggage, and will there be space for them? Are we going to be able to pick them up in the early morning?

Comment: SHF seems to be Shihezi Huayuan Airport, (which would be a bit of a detour coming from Leipzig), do you mean SXF (Schönefeld) ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please try to limit the scope of the question; Stack Exchange is about finding specific answers to specific questions, and things like "how to spend a good 1-day" are much too broad and subjective to be answered adequately in our format. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: If you're staying less than 18 hours and would be willing to leave your luggage at the airport or the train station, then you obviously can't need it very badly - why are you bringing luggage at all?

Comment: Yes, I meant SXF, and going to look at the site tour. I need to luggage because I'm coming from 3 days at Leipzig, so I can't come without them.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't give advice on what attractions to visit.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I didn't ask about attraction, but tips about a day, the new year's eve one, in Berlin!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brandenburg Gate will be horribly crowded, but so will be all clubs. If you come from Schönefeld Airport (I assume that is what you meant, IATA code is actually SXF) it might make more sense to store your luggage at Südkreuz Station (which has a direct connection to Schönefeld) because from there you can switch trains (from S45 to S2) to go to Brandenburg Gate (although this will be really, really crowded). Details for luggage storage at Südkreuz are [e.g. here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57618/where-can-i-leave-luggage-in-berlin-and-be-able-to-pick-it-late-at-night/57661#57661). If you are up for a walk or rent some bicycles there is a cycle track along the Metro line from Südkreuz to Potsdamer Platz that should take thirty Minutes at max (and from there you are pretty close to Brandenburger Tor). Scenery is nice, but at New Years eve you might not be very interested in sightseeing.

Judging by the [lineup for the last New Year's party](https://www.berlin.de/events/3303144-2229501-silvesterparty-am-brandenburger-tor.html) ("DJ BoBo, Jermaine Jackson, Marianne Rosenberg, Rainhard Fendrich, Max Giesinger, Bonnie Tyler, Peter Schilling, Fun Factory, La Bouche, Kerstin Ott, Wincent Weiss, Venga Boys, Ray Wilson, Radio Future und die Hermes House Band ") you actually might want to avoid Brandenburger Tor if you insist on Techno, but if you are simply looking for a huge party then you should be fine (alas at 46 I don't think I can recommend anything that would be much fun for a group of 19 year olds).

You can look at https://www.berliner-silvester.de/ to get updates on the planned festivities (I also recommend to read the bit about security checks).

Comment: They are coming from Leipzig, not from SXF. They just considered it for luggage storage. But IIRC the Leipzig connection trains actually stop in Suedkreuz too.

Comment: @simbabque, yes, I should have read that more thoroughly. I already wondered, since AFAIK the flight from Leipzig to Berlin makes a stop at Munich and thus takes twice as long as the train.